# multiple ping to hosts using python with linux

Tags: python, linux, networking, ping

I have some questions.
I'm in Linux and I need to check ping for 254 pc at once with python
for example :

I have IP address 10.1.1.1 ... 10.1.1.254
and all I need is to check if I have successfully ping to this pc using python.

so the total output should be :

the pc 10.1.1.1 Pinging

the pc 10.1.1.2 Not Pinging

the pc 10.1.1.3 Pinging

So on until 10.1.1.254

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess


ips = ["192.168.1.{}".format(i) for i in range(1,255)]
mainList = set()
def ping(ips):
    for num,i in enumerate(ips):
        print(f'Searching Host {i}    Itration Number {num}')
        try:
            p = subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c1', i], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            p.communicate(timeout=(0.1))
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            pass
        else:
            print(f'***Host found - Add to array***')
            mainList.add(i)
    print(mainList)

ping(ips)
```